# Return option of member depending on option of containing object

Tags: scala

Assume I have the following:

```
case class Person(val name: String) {}

def personName(person: Option[Person]): Option[String] = {
  // if person is a Some(Person) Some(person.get.name) else None
}
```

My point is, how to easily (in one line) return an option of the person's name, depending on whether or not the person is a Some or a None?

I could easily do this with pattern matching, like this

```
def personName(person: Option[Person]): Option[String] = {
  person match {
    case Some(p) => Some(p.name)
    case None => None
  }
}
```

And I could easily write a generic function for this, like this

```
def optionalAttribute[T, AT](obj: Option[T], attribute: => AT): Option[AT] = {
  obj match {
    case Some(t) => Some(attribute)
    case None => None
  }
}
```

But knowing Scala, there must be an easier (one line) way to accomplish this.

What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def personName(person: Option[Person]): Option[String] = person.map(_.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

And indeed I was overlooking something simple. Collegue pointed it out.

```
for (p <- person) yield p.name
```